# if statement for first two characters of string

Tags: java

i need help with the if statement. if the ticket doesn't begin with the particular string then it prompts them with "invalid, try again", an example of a ticket is BA200

```
public class Game
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter Ticket");
      String ticket = keyboard.nextLine();
      if(ticket=("AB"|| "ab" || "BA" || "ba" || "CB" || "cb"))
      {
         System.out.println("correct");
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("invalid, try again");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: You've made a few mistakes in your code and to be honest it would be better to just use String::startsWith

Comment: @Aominè thats why I'm asking for help, I'm useless at this!!

Comment: Use following code to match. if (ticket != null && ticket.length() >= 2 && ticket.toUpperCase().matches("(AB|BA|BC|CB|AC|CA).*"))

Answer (score 3):

Use the startsWith method:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Game
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter Ticket");
    String ticket = keyboard.nextLine();
    if(ticket.toUpperCase().trim().startsWith("AB") || 
            ticket.toUpperCase().trim().startsWith("BA") || 
            ticket.toUpperCase().trim().startsWith("CB") )
    {
        System.out.println("correct");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("invalid, try again");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Add all valid prefixes in a List.
2. when you read the input, extract the two first characters of the String and check if it matches with one of the valid patterns.

It could give:

```
  List<String> validPrefixes = Arrays.asList("AB","BA","CB");

  if(ticket.length() >=2 && validPrefixes.contains(ticket.subString(0,2).toUpperCase()){
     System.out.println("correct");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. You are welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

Change your `if` statement to something like following:

```
if(ticket.toUpperCase().startsWith("AB") || 
   ticket.toUpperCase().startsWith("BA") || 
   ticket.toUpperCase().startsWith("CB") )
```

Comment: great, thanks for the help!!

Comment: @Majeet. You are welcome. Happy learning.